# Ruby ERB render and def function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I got an strange issue with my experiments with ERB. Here what code do I have:

```
# cat ./services_lbs2.erb
<%= def renderVip(description, template)
puts "zxc dfg"
end
%>
# locally and remote
Printing: <%= renderVip('123','456') %>
```

And here what I am getting in the irb:

```
irb(main):034:0> @template=File.read('./services_lbs2.erb')
=> "<%= def renderVip(description, template)\nputs \"zxc dfg\"\nend\n%>\n# locally and remotely monitored (all externals)\nPrinting: <%= renderVip('123','456') %>\n"
irb(main):035:0> zxc = ERB.new(@template,nil, "-")
=> #<ERB:0x00000000068d4d88 @safe_level=nil, @src="#coding:US-ASCII\n_erbout = String.new; _erbout.concat(( def renderVip(description, template)\nputs \"zxc dfg\"\nend\n).to_s); _erbout.concat \"\\n# locally and remotely monitored (all externals)\\nPrinting: \"\n\n; _erbout.concat(( renderVip('123','456') ).to_s); _erbout.concat \"\\n\"\n; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)", @encoding=#<Encoding:US-ASCII>, @frozen_string=nil, @filename=nil, @lineno=0>
irb(main):036:0> zxc.result(binding)
zxc dfg
=> "renderVip\n# locally and remotely monitored (all externals)\nPrinting: \n"
```

I could not get the output like:

```
# locally and remotely monitored (all externals)\nPrinting: zxc dfg\n
```

Why is it so and how it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: return the value directly from that method instead of puts-ing it.

Comment: It can be option for this case, but what I was looking for is to print 
<%= render './path_to_another_template' %> from the renderVip function. The goal is to have template with several partials included into it which are rendering with specific parameters

Comment: So what's the problem with that? Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value `puts` function is `nil` so in your case, the method will return `nil`.

So after execution `nil` is being appended inside the `body` tag. For this to work change it to

```
<% 
  def renderVip(description, template)
    "zxc dfg"
  end
%>
```

Comment: I would recommend dropping the `=` so that the symbol `:renderVip` (returned by the method definition) does not leak into the output

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated the answer.